# Slow read from s3 using pyspark for 500k small parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3, parquet

I have been working on a transformation system where the source is large number of small parquet files (~150 KB) stored in s3. When I try to read these files in my pyspark job using  `spark.read.parquet(*keys)` it takes a lot of time. The reading alone is take in neighborhood of 1hr for a 40CPU cluster. All these parquet files have same schema.

While searching around I came across "spark small file" problem. So I tried implementing a compactor which would preread these parquet files, repartition them and persist on PVC. Even this approach I am stuck with high read time for the compactor.

To get the files from s3 to local PVC i tried creating a spark job that download the keys using Boto3 client and download them to compact later so that my transformation job will be quick. The download speed that i get using boto3 client is significantly faster then the read operation.

Is there an other optimized way to read these files ? Or should I download these files to PVC using spark boto3 and then write a utility to compact them.

Update:
the actual instance that i am testing against is MinIO instance.
the key prefix has metadata that i need to read as well.
example : {bucket_name}/{metadata1=abc}/{metadata2=abc}/{metadata3=abc}/data.parquet

[update]
sample code snippet that i have been using - this code creates directories for all the specified s3 keys but only download around ~3000 of them (from 84000) and mark the job as complete
(20 executors 1GB ram / 1 Core each)

```
import os
import time
import json

import boto3
from pyspark import TaskContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def process_files(broadcast_obj, iterator):     
    broadcast_vars = broadcast_obj.value
    local_dir = broadcast_vars["local_dir"]
    bucket_name = broadcast_vars["bucket_name"]
    endpoint_url = broadcast_vars["endpoint_url"]
    aws_access_key_id = broadcast_vars["aws_access_key_id"]
    aws_secret_access_key = broadcast_vars["aws_secret_access_key"]
    executor_id = TaskContext().get().taskAttemptId()
    error_keys = list()
    s3 = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
        config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version="s3v4"),
        verify=False,
    )
    start_time = time.time()
    with open( f"{local_dir}/timing_info_executor_{executor_id}_{str(time.time())}.txt", "w") as file:
        key_count = 0
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
            futures = []
            for key in keys:
                local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, key)
                key_count += 1
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(local_path), exist_ok=True)
                future = executor.submit(lambda x: s3.download_file(bucket_name, key, local_path), key)
                futures.append(future)
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                try:
                    res = future.result()
                except Exception as e:
                    error_keys.append(e)
                    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        file.write(f"Failed {error_keys} ")
        file.write(f"Processed {key_count} in {time.time() - start_time} seconds\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_json_path = f'/data/jsonfile.json'
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("s3Downloader")
    broadcast_vars = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(
            {
                "endpoint_url": "objec_store_creds",  
                "aws_access_key_id": "objec_store_creds",
                "aws_secret_access_key": "objec_store_creds",
                "local_dir": f'/data/temp',
                "bucket_name": 'my-bucket',
            }
        )
    s3keys = None
    with open(local_json_path, "r") as read_content: 
        s3keys = json.load(read_content)
        
    num_partitions = s3keys/700
    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
                s3keys, num_partitions
            )
    rdd.foreachPartition(lambda p: process_files(broadcast_vars, p))
    spark.stop()
```

Comment: AWS S3 has limitations on the number of concurrent read requests it can process in parallel. The best way to avoid is to split the files into a hierarchical directory structure. and use glob matching to specify all the subdirectories. 

https://repost.aws/questions/QU_F-UC6-fSdOYzp-gZSDTvQ/receiving-s3-503-slow-down-responses

Comment: I would suggest to compact these files into bigger files and then upload to S3 for better reading speed.

Comment: You can copy the data to local hdfs using s3-dist-cp and can use targetSize property to control the size of the data which will compact the data: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Looks like the way to go but currently i do not have a hdfs available.

Comment: @user238607 the cloud storage that i am using is an instance of s3 for the benchmarking purpose and intend to make the setup cloud agnostic hence, most probably will be hitting an S3proxy which in turn request the relevant object storage. Removing hierarchical directory structure do help but the UP stream has fixed pattern an cannot be changed.

Comment: I am sure all cloud providers will have such throttle limits, so you will need to handle them everywhere i.e for all cloud providers. Why not solve this problem right now itself and change the upstream.

Comment: @user238607 You are correct, but from the results I have I am not currently able to hit throttling limit yet. 84000 keys in 1hr. Its just 1400 keys a min.

Answer (score 1):

Parquet queries are suboptimal on cloud as the seek() operations force multiple GET requests (footer, schema, ranges...). best to use the final stage of any query to coalesce the files to a small number of larger ones. Like you note: pulling all the files to a single local host (one GET per file), coalesce and write there probably is the most efficient.

You are limited to 5000 reads/second down a single s3 partitions, so the multiple GET requests issued on parquet reads could well limit you to processing 1500 files/second before throttling is encountered. This will trigger exponential sleep and backoff so can significantly hurt throughput.

When downloading locally, it takes effort to generate those 5000 reads, though within EC2 it is possible. Consider using some kind of rate limiter (e.g. google guava's) to hold back the reads below the threshold.

Finally, aim for 256MB or more per file. This is where overheads of listing/reading files become less important.

For anyone curious about ORC/Parquet IO in cloud, see: [An Empirical Evaluation of Columnar Storage Formats](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.05028.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

How much data are you talking about?

I've written compaction routines before using pandas; I'd probably use [polars](https://pola.rs/) if I were doing it today. You don't need Spark and I suspect the compaction process will be simpler and faster if you avoid using it.

Here's an approach you could start with:

- get a listing of all files. If they are partitioned, perhaps get a listing of all partitions, and then for each partition get a listing of all files. i.e. use `boto3.client('s3').list_objects`.
- split these files up into appropriate sized buckets, e.g. between 100MB and 500MB per bucket.
- for each bucket, read each file to DataFrame and union them together
- write an output file to the appropriate location / partition.

Ideally write the new files to a different bucket/prefix, so that you can verify (spot check) you've not lost any data.

---

Here's an (untested) example that demonstrates this approach. You need to provide the list of partitions; you could get this by inspecting S3, but may be able to more easily get from e.g. Hive / Glue.

```
import boto3
import polars as pl

source_bucket = "source_bucket"
target_bucket = "target_bucket"
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

# write a function to get all the unique partition prefixes
# e.g. every {metadata1=abc}/{metadata2=abc}/... combination
partition_prefixes = get_partitions(source_bucket)

# Iterate through each partition
for prefix in partition_prefixes:
    # find all the keys for a specific partition
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    keys = [o["Key"] for o in response["Contents"]]

    # read all files then concat; you could also read & concat one by one
    dfs = [pl.read_parquet(f"s3://{source_bucket}/{key}") for key in keys]
    combined = pl.concat(dfs)

    combined.write_parquet(f"s3://{target_bucket}/{prefix}/combined.parquet")
```

Comment: the data is in terms of ~700000(files) totaling to  ~90GB an hour